# Regex в MongoDB - исключить подстроку

Tags: регулярные-выражения, mongodb

Ищу по distinct User-Agent'ы. Использую регулярные выражения, суть в следующем:
Мне надо, чтобы он выбирал заголовки, которые начинаются с (Mozilla|Opera|Firefox), но не содержат подстроку YandexMetrika. Конструкция получилась такая: `/(Mozilla|Opera|Firefox)((?!YandexMetrika).)*/`. Это работает, но не до конца. Строки, которые начинающиеся с искомых слов, выбираются (другие отсеиваются), НО: строки, которые содержат YandexMetrika, всё равно остаются. Как сделать чтобы он понимал, что нужно исключать строки, содержащие `YandexMetrika`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
/^(?!.*YandexMetrika)(Mozilla|Opera|Firefox)/
```

Сначала проверка на исключение, чтобы подстроки `YandexMetrika` не было в строке, а потом уже проверка на наличие `Mozilla|Opera|Firefox` в начале строки. `^` - начало строки.